# Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'

Tags: mysql

I've copied a sql function to try to use it for filtering out HTML data during a search operation, but using that function throws the error in the title.

This is the function + drop statement if needed:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS StripTags;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION StripTags( Dirty varchar(255) )
  RETURNS varchar(255) 
DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
  END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

And this is the query. As you can see I was searching for 'p' to check if the

tags would be present in the results.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        `products`.*,
        max(( CASE WHEN LOWER(StripTags(`product_code`))
                    LIKE 'p' THEN
                    600
                ELSE
                    0
END) + ( CASE WHEN LOWER(StripTags(`product_code`))
        LIKE 'p%' THEN
        200
    ELSE
        0
END) + ( CASE WHEN LOWER(StripTags(`product_code`))
        LIKE '%p%' THEN
        40
    ELSE
        0
END) + ( CASE WHEN LOWER(StripTags(`description`))
        LIKE 'p' THEN
        600
    ELSE
        0
END) + ( CASE WHEN LOWER(StripTags(`description`))
        LIKE 'p%' THEN
        200
    ELSE
        0
END) + ( CASE WHEN LOWER(StripTags(`description`))
        LIKE '%p%' THEN
        40
    ELSE
        0
END)) AS relevance
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`organisation_id` = '2'
GROUP BY
    `products`.`id`
HAVING
    relevance >= 40.00
ORDER BY
    `relevance` DESC) AS `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`organisation_id` = '2'
ORDER BY
    `products`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 200 offset 0;
```

I've tried using different collations at different points, but aside from some different errors (`COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'`) I did not feel like I was closer to the answer.

If anyone has any idea, please let me know!.